# How to use conditional OR in arm template?

Tags: azure, conditional-statements, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage, azure-rm-template

I'm trying to create a private endpoint through an ARM template for a storage account if the storage account SKU is Standard_GRS or Standard_RAGRS, or Standard_GZRS. How to include this in the conditional statement in the ARM template.

Answer (score 1):

We have tested this in our local environment, below statements are based on our analysis.

In our local environment, we have created an ARM template to deploy storage account a condition the SKU of the storage account should be either of the below :

- "Standard_GRS", "Standard_RAGRS", "Standard_GZRS"

To achieve this we have used the below condition in our ARM template :

```
"condition":"[or(equals(parameters('sku'),'Standard_RAGRS'),equals(parameters('sku'),'Standard_GZRS'),equals(parameters('sku'),'Standard_GRS'))]",
```

**Here is the ARM template that we have used:**

```html
    {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "parameters": {
            "sku": {
                "type": "string"
            }
        },
        "functions": [],
        "variables": {
        },
        "resources": [
      {
         "condition":"[or(equals(parameters('sku'),'Standard_RAGRS'),equals(parameters('sku'),'Standard_GZRS'),equals(parameters('sku'),'Standard_GRS'))]",
          "name": "<strgaccount>",
          "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
          "apiVersion": "2021-04-01",
          "tags": {
              "displayName": "storageaccount1"
          },
          "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
          "kind": "StorageV2",
          "sku": {
              "name": "[parameters('sku')]"
          }
      }
        ],
        "outputs": {}
    }
```

**Here is the sample output for reference:**

- In the below Output we have passed the SKU value "Standard_GZRS" the condition got succeeded and Resource got deployed.

[image]

- In the below Output we have passed the SKU value "Standard_LRS" the condition got failed & the resource didn't get deployed.

[image]